# issues deploying flask app in cpanel ( Namecheap)

Tags: flask, deployment, hosting

I am having issues deploying flask app in cpanel. I uploaded the flask app to file manager in cpanel. I created an app but still not working? Is there a specific principles creating a virtual environment in cpanel?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem where only the root URL would work and all other routes returned 404.

Add the following to the top of your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE]
```

Got this info from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63971427/10122266

Apologies that I couldn't add this as a comment as I do not have sufficient rights yet. But this solution worked for me and it would be a pitty if this little gem is hidden from those who may arrive here.

So would appreciate if this post is not deleted.